# Cannot Install Watch App

Tags: apple-watch, testflight

I was able to archive, submit to iTunes and turn on test flight to have internal testers. Everything is fine on the iPhone, the app is working and doing what it's suppose to do but when you turn test flight on for the apple watch app I get this error message ""AppName" is installed on your iPhone, but the "AppName" app for Apple Watch is currently unavailable."

I have the latest beta's and I've tried restarting both my watch and iPhone.

Comment: I have this same exact issue. We just deployed on friday and have the same exact alert across all devices on iOS 9 with a paired watch. Unfortunately haven't found much of a solution other than trying to unpair and re-pair the watch and phone combo but that hasn't worked for us.